# what are core concept of sectionView, ListView and FlatList?

Tags: react-native

I'm very new to react-native. I want to know what are the core differences among SectionView, ListView and FlatView in react-native? And what cases I should use them.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views

Answer (score 3):

### [ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview)  (Deprecated)

[image: FlatList/ListView]

It is an deprecated class which was used to create List. You can also read [List documentation.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview)

> DEPRECATED - use one of the new list components, such as FlatList or
>   SectionList

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
/>
```

### [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)

[image: FlatList/ListView]

Now you should use this class to create Lists. Its performance is better than ListView. Because ListView was slow with large data. But FlatList manage it significantly.

It has many features over ListView

- Fully cross-platform.
- Optional horizontal mode.
- Configurable viewability callbacks.
- Header support.
- Footer support.
- Separator support.
- Pull to Refresh.
- Scroll loading.
- ScrollToIndex support.

Here is how FlatList is created

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

## [SecionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist)

[image: SectionList]

Used when one need a list to be divided into sections. Its implementation is bit different from FlatList. It needs two items.

1. Title/Header
2. Data

It has all FlatList features and has section support also.

- Fully cross-platform.
- Configurable viewability callbacks.
- List header support.
- List footer support.
- Item separator support.
- Section header support.
- Section separator support.
- Heterogeneous data and item rendering support.
- Pull to Refresh.
- Scroll loading.

Here is implementation

```
// Example 1 (Homogeneous Rendering)
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>}
  renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
  )}
  sections={[
    {title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2']},
    {title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4']},
    {title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6']},
  ]}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
/>
```